# How to filter this NSArray of multiples NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that nested multiples dictionaries like this:

```
anArray = 
{
    "identifier1" =     {
        "3498239502323120" =         {
            key1 = abc;
            key2 = 123;
        };
        "3493208429034821" =         {
            key1 = def;
            key2 = 456;
        };
    },
    "identifier2" =     {
        "456434234234" =         {
            key1 = ghi;
            key2 = 789;
        };
        "8796554" =         {
            key1 = jkl;
            key2 = 101112;
        };
    };
}
```

I'm only interested in all values of the `key1` in `identifier1`. I expect an output of:

```
filteredArray =
[
    abc,
    def
]
```

Any idea what is the predicate format I should use in my code below? Preferably without looping. I'm honestly confused by the formatting in `NSPredicate`.

```
NSArray *filteredArray =[anArray[identifier] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"what's the format here?"]];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want a transformation of your data, and a filtering, no? That's two different steps.

Comment: Could you explain more about this?

Comment: When you filter, you retrieve the SAME information, minus some elements. For instance, you have an Array of Dictionary, and in the end you want an array of String, no? That's why it might not be done only with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

Comment: You have to do all mannually: https://pastebin.com/a8RxE07t

Comment: Hmm, that is the best way to do this I guess? Thanks for the explanation.